# Assigning a group to root of site collection for permisisons

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, sharepoint-rest-api

Does anyone know from the top of their head, the REST API call for assigning a group and a permission to a root of a site collection.?

I have been trawling through the documnetation for the last hour or so and I cannot find a way of doing it at

> _api/webs location